Typeorm ordering does not work with subquery
I have an Entity like this:
@Entity()
export class CourseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => BoughtCourseEntity, (boughtCourse) => boughtCourse.course)
  boughtCourses!: Array<BoughtCourseEntity>;

  @Column({ select: false, insert: false, readonly: true, nullable: true })
  boughtCoursesCount: number;

  constructor(partial: Partial<CourseEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}

In my queryBuilder I assign a value to boughtCoursesCount and then I want to do the ordering by this column but it does not work without any errors:
      query.addSelect((subQuery) => {
        return subQuery
          .select('COUNT(bc.id)', 'boughtCoursesCount')
          .from('bought_course_entity', 'bc')
          .where('bc.courseId = course.id');
      }, 'course_boughtCoursesCount');


      

And then I do orderBy('course.boughtCoursesCount'). I guess the problem might be due to some naming conventions but not sure what could I do here.
